# error when changing marker in leaflet geosearch

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

I'm using Vue2-leaflet-geosearch (https://github.com/fega/vue2-leaflet-geosearch) and i'm trying to change the default marker with the following code

```
import { OpenStreetMapProvider } from 'leaflet-geosearch';
import VGeosearch from 'vue2-leaflet-geosearch';
import { icon } from "leaflet";

export default {
    components: { VGeosearch },
    data() {
        return {
            geosearchOptions: {
                provider: new OpenStreetMapProvider(),
                marker: {
                    iconRetinaUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico',
                    iconUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where the property `marker` represents the configuration of the marker, as it says in the documentation
(https://smeijer.github.io/leaflet-geosearch/leaflet-control) `marker: MarkerOptions` the default marker does not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply trying to pass directly options for an Icon, instead of expected options for a Marker (which in particular can receive an `icon` option).

See the doc section "Show result" of https://github.com/smeijer/leaflet-geosearch#geosearchcontrol

> `marker` can be set to any instance of a (custom) `L.Icon`.

```js
new GeoSearchControl({
  marker: {
    // optional: L.Marker    - default L.Icon.Default
    icon: new L.Icon.Default(),
    draggable: false,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let MyCustomMarker = L.Icon.extend({
  options: {
    iconUrl: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Information_icon4_orange.svg'
  }
});
new GeoSearchControl({
  marker: {
    icon: new MyCustomMarker(),
    draggable: false,
  }
});
```